# Interactive US map with JQuery

Tags: jquery, dictionary, z-index

I have a page with an interactive US map. Each state is an image that is interchangeable based on settings from the database (it's not one big image and/or an image map). I also have an unordered list (items absolutely positioned over its corresponding state) set as a clickable element to change the content of a div. The div contains all of the content in their own divs; which div is shown is based on having a class of "active."
The script and the markup can be viewed here: https://gist.github.com/3239999

Due to the overlap of the png images, the image itself cannot reliably be the clickable element, but I wanted the state to direct the link if possible.

The code in the gist works everywhere but in IE for the small states in the New England/East Coast area. I can resolve it with a little z-index work, but it's not flawless. In some cases you have to click on just the right spot still (which is not immediately obvious).

I'm open to just using a different script for IE, but I can't seem to change it to only use the li as the indicator and work in IE.
I have tried this without success:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        switchers = $('#switchers > li');
        states = $('#state_info > div');
        switchers.each(function(idx) {
            $(this).data('state', states.eq(idx));
        }).click(function() {
             switchers.removeClass('active');
             states.removeClass('active');             
             $("#_" + $(this).attr('id')).addClass('active');  
             $("#_" + $(this).attr('id')).data('state').addClass('active');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm not as jquery savvy as I'd like to be, especially to troubleshoot cross browser issues.

Can anyone help me get this working better?

You can see the mostly working version here: http://www.envisiondemo.com/lookout/state-and-federal-i-9-compliance/

The actual site is live, but I am using a demo server to test. I've styled the li's to have a red border in IE, which helps you see where the problem areas are. It seems that the worst is West Virginia and Virginia. Since they hug each other from an angle, I can't change the z-index to fix it. One will always be overly overlapping the other.

Comment: Hey Radu, Could you elaborate on what you mean by "do it with SVG"?

Comment: I have understood SVG as an image type...it seems to be used as a flash-like solution for the web.

Comment: IE doesn't directly support SVG, so that seems potentially problematic especially when I'm trying to address a problem with IE as it is. Is there a solution that doesn't require rebuilding the entire map?

Comment: Check out http://raphaeljs.com/. With that you can support even IE6. The great part here is that each state can be its own clickable object, and on top of that you get the benefits of vector graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Other that looking at switching it to SVG (which I admit may be a bit extreme given that it seems you're pretty far along, I can recommend the following:

Use a single background image so you can avoid absolutely positioning all the images of the states. So instead of having the following code:

```
<div id="states">
    <img />
    <img />
</div>

<ul id="switchers">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

you could have just:

```
<ul id="states">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

and set the map with `background-url`. Finally, I would actually add the names of the states to the `li` elements rather than have them in the image. This allows you to possibly highlight on hover.

Your script could be improved as follows:

http://jsfiddle.net/radu/4bVcd/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $switchers = $('#switchers li'),
        $states = $('#state_info div');

    $switchers.click(function() {
        $switchers.removeClass('active');
        $states.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('#_' + this.id).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

In your script `switchers` and `states` were implicit globals since the `var` statement was not present. I prefix my jQuery objects with `$` but that's just personal preference.

In your code, you linked `state_info` to `switchers` via jQuery's `.data()`, but I'm not sure you were using that properly and it was throwing errors every click.

As far as your issue with IE6, I recommend maybe moving WV or VA out with the other east coast states. Even in browsers where this works fine, it's a bit difficult to pick it out. To further improve usability you could do what I mentioned earlier, and somehow highlight the state name on hover. You can change the color, increase the size, add a shadow.. whatever, as long as its clear to the user which state is being selected. 
​